# Keeping only year and month in axis of a matplotlib plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels, python-datetime

When using `datetime` objects as axis ticks in a matplotlib plot, I would like to only report year and month. But instead, using my code below, the x axis includes also days, hours, minutes ans seconds. Is there a simple way to remove these, so that only the month and year remain?

The formatting is not crucial. That is, it could be either like `2015-12` or like `December 2015`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
arr = [1,2,3,4]
ax.scatter(arr, arr)
firstDate = datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 18)
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([ firstDate+datetime.timedelta(7*tick) for tick in ticks])
plt.xticks(fontsize=12, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: is there a reason to not convert your x-argument to a list of datetime or a numpy.datenum64?  Then you can use the automatic dateticking...  Or specify https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator

Comment: If not, you can format the tick using datetime.strftime https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html